# MsGraph OneDrive and Preservation Hold library

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

For some reason request [`GET /my/drives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#list-the-current-users-drives) for OneDrive Business accounts returns "Preservation Hold library" in collection of user's drives.

"Preservation Hold library" [`drive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/drive?view=graph-rest-1.0) has language specific `description`: "*This library contains items that have been modified or deleted but must remain available due to eDiscovery holds. Items cannot be modified or removed*" and `webUrl` like "*https://[tenant]-my.sharepoint.com/personal/[account_name]/PreservationHoldLibrary*".

How to detect at runtime which drive is linked with "Preservation Hold library" so as to filter it out of processing?

I believe that parsing `webUrl` field is not reliable way.

**UPDATE**:
[Question on Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/487059/graph-returns-34preservation-hold-library34-as-one.html).